# qTip and dynamic content

Tags: javascript, html, qtip

I am new to JavaScript and qTip and I can't manage to do something. I have a table with images and I need a qTip with the image's description for each one of them. I load the images and the content from the database. How do I write this? From what I've read I need to add the description to a hidden div and access the div from the JavaScript function. The only problem is I don't know how. Cold you please show me how to do this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: This is the function I use: $('table.logos: td').qtip({
    content: 'Test Content',
    show: 'mouseover',
    hide: 'mouseout',
    position: 
    {
      corner: 
      {
        target: 'topMiddle',
        tooltip: 'bottomMiddle'
      }
    },
  }); The problem is, I want each image to have its description as content inside the qTip. I didn't try anything yet since I don't know how that should be written. All I know is that it has something to do with accessing a hidden div from that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your HTML markup looks more or less like this:

```
<td>
    <img title="First img">
</td>
<td>
    <img title="Second img">
</td>
```

Here's what you can do:

```
$('td').each(function() {
    var img = $('img', this);
    $(this).qtip({
        content: img.attr('title'),
        show: 'mouseover',
        hide: 'mouseout',
        position: {
             target: 'topMiddle',
             tooltip: 'bottomMiddle'
        }
    });
});
```

The idea is to go through all holders, get the underlying image and the tooltip content (in this case `img.attr('title')`) and generate tooltip with this custom `content`.